# Backbone.js View not rendering my json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am new to backbone.js and want to render a json file, called `products.json`.

The products get loaded into the collection, but it just won´t render. I am having problems 
with the `render()` function & underscore.js .

If anyone can help me, thank you!

Comment: looks an error here ProductItemView = Backbone.Model.extend, maybe ProductItemView = Backbone.View.extend ?

Comment: Thanks, I changed it, but still not rendering.

Comment: @zer02 - you are missing toJSON in the template function, instead of item: this.model - put item: this.model.toJSON()

Comment: Please remove the solution part from your question. It should be in an answer instead.

Comment: You deleted my answer @ThiefMaster

Comment: Actually the idea should be to accept the answer that helped you solving the question. I don't know from where your edit is different to my answer where I suggested you to add the listener and fire the reset event. Afterwards you asked about the `item.attributes` but I don't know if you have tried it or not.

Comment: There were two things missing to make it work. `item.attributes` , `.el` append and `this.model.toJSON()` did not work.

Comment: Removed answer from question and added as a community wiki. You should of posted the answer as an answer. This is what ThiefMaster is on about.

Comment: @Liam I did! He deleted it, if you check the history...

Comment: I did 2 answer. first one got deleted. second one got deleted, too. So I did not delete the answer in my question. If you guys don´t give any comments for the reason of deletion this is bad moding. Better to have an solution in the question thread as edit than deleting all my answers without a reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **ShopView** you have to add a listener for the 'reset' event in the collection, so the view will get re-rendered when the collection is fetched.

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.collection = new ShopList();
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render, this);
    this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
    // Check URL Path 
    this.render();        
}

render: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.collection.each(function(item) {
        var view = new ProductItemView({
            model: item
        });
        $(self.el).append(view.render());
    });
    return this;
}
```

To render the model you have to change the template to look like this:

```
<span class="product_name"><%= product_name %></span><br />
<span class="product_price"><%= price %></span>
```

And the render of the **ProductItemView**:

```
render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to add this. It still does not render my products.json.

Comment: How many times does the view get logged in the line `console.log(view)`?

Comment: `console.log(view)`does not execute, it says `this.collection.length` is 0. I added the `console.log(this.collection)`

Comment: Add `return self;` to your render method. If not change that `console.log(view);` for `console.log(item);` to check what it's logging.

Comment: I added still not working :/

Comment: I have updated my answer with the render method. You can try it an let me know. Add also the `console.log(item)` to check what is logging.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47667/discussion-between-puigcerber-and-zer02)

Comment: Hello thank you, I am using your render method. `console.log(item)`is empty. the whole loop is not running, but `render function()` gets executed. So it has to be something with `this.collection.each` problem.

Comment: Please @zer02, check the chat...

Comment: Hey, I finally did it! I explain to you how, but still it does not seems to be the best solution. Thanks again Puigcerber for your help.

Comment: I hope you understood what the problem was. The view gets rendered before the collection it's fetched, so that's why you have to trigger the 'reset' event when the collection it's fetched and listen to it to re-render the view. So I think you can accept the answer to close the issue. I'm going to update it with what I think it's your problem with `item.attributes`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert your models to JSON using the `toJSON` function

replace:

```
$(this.el).html(this.template({
            item: this.model
}));
```

with:

```
 $(this.el).html(this.template({
            item: this.model.toJSON()
 }));
```

Comment: Hello, i tried. Still no success, I don´t know why `console.log(view)` is empty, it does not loop.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, 
you are doing everything right.
only while rending and putting data you are making mistake. In backbone model we access values of backbone mdel by getters not by .
change your html like this

```
<script type="text/template" id="shop_template" >
<div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:10px">
   <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
   <img src="<%= item.get('img') %>" alt="image" style="width:150px" id="<%= item.get('id') %>" draggable="true"
      ondragstart="drag(event)">
   <br>
   <span class="product_name"><%= item.get('product_name') %></span><br>
   <span class="product_price"><%= item.get('price') %></span>
   </a>
</div>
</script>
```

Try your luck..
One final tip. try using coffeescript with backbone. You need to code less and in clean way. i hardly work in js.

Comment: hello, thanks. But I guess the problem is somewhere with the collection. I does not do the `each` loop

Answer (score 0):

OP answered his own question:

```
 render: function() {
            var self = this;
            console.log(this.collection);
            _(this.collection.models).each(function(item) {
                console.log(item);
                console.log('render!');
                var view = new ProductItemView({
                    model: item.attributes
                });
                $(self.el).append(view.render().el);
            });
            return this;
        }
```

I had to add `$(self.el).append(view.render().el)` and `item.attributes`

And thanks @Puigcerber

for his advice to use: `this.collection.fetch({reset: true})`

---

**Here is my code:**

*Underscore.js Template:*

```
<script type="text/template" id="shop_template" >
<div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:10px">
   <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
   <img src="<%= item.img %>" alt="image" style="width:150px" id="<%= item.id %>" draggable="true"
      ondragstart="drag(event)">
   <br>
   <span class="product_name"><%= item.product_name %></span><br>
   <span class="product_price"><%= item.price %></span>
   </a>
</div>
</script>
```

*Backbone Code:*

```
(function($) {
    var ProductItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            id: 'id',
            price: '1,99€',
            img: 'url',
            product_name: 'name'
        }
    });
    var ShopList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ProductItem,
        url: '/products.json'
    });
    var ProductItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        template: _.template($("#shop_template").html()),
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        },
        render: function() {
            $(this.el).html(this.template({
                item: this.model
            }));
            return this;
        }
    });
    var ShopView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#product_ul'),
        events: {
        },
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.collection = new ShopList();
            this.collection.fetch();
            // Check URL Path 
            this.render();
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render, this);
        },
        render: function() {
            var self = this;
            this.collection.each(function(item) {
                var view = new ProductItemView({
                    model: item
                });
                $(this.el).append(view.render());
                console.log(view);
            });
           return this;
        }
    });
    var shopView = new ShopView();
    //console.log(shopView);
})(jQuery);
```

*products.json:*

```
[
    {
        "id": "prod_0",
        "price": 85,
        "img": "images/0.jpg",
        "product_name": "Joni Ward"
    },
    {
        "id": "prod_1",
        "price": 73,
        "img": "images/1.jpg",
        "product_name": "Ofelia Ross"
    },
    {
        "id": "prod_2",
        "price": 37,
        "img": "images/2.jpg",
        "product_name": "Nell Anthony"
    },
    {
        "id": "prod_3",
        "price": 60,
        "img": "images/3.jpg",
        "product_name": "Schneider Benton"
    },
    {
        "id": "prod_4",
        "price": 13,
        "img": "images/4.jpg",
        "product_name": "Abigail Newman"
    }
]
```

*this.collection object (console inspector):*

```
s
_byId: Object
_events: Object
_listenId: "l2"
length: 5
models: Array[5]
0: s
_changing: false
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
id: "prod_0"
img: "images/0.jpg"
price: 85
product_name: "Joni Ward"
__proto__: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c3"
collection: s
id: "prod_0"
__proto__: n
1: s
2: s
3: s
4: s
length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__:
```